What is $\prod_{p}\frac{p}{ \sqrt{p^2 + 1}}$?
[Edited] Fascinated by $\pi = \sqrt{6} \prod_{p}\frac{p}{ \sqrt{p^2 - 1}}$ - a consequence of the famous "Basel problem" - I'm curious what $\prod_{p}\frac{p}{ \sqrt{p^2 + 1}}$ might be. Numerically I found 0.8111557... Can you give me any hints how to find the actual value of this infinite product?
And a second related question, when creating the same product over all natural numbers instead of just the primes, i.e. $\prod_{n}\frac{n}{ \sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$, I get numerically 0.52156404... What's this number?

Why is this a consequence of the Basel problem?

OP is saying the product of $\pi = \sqrt 6 \prod_p \frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2-1}}$ is a consequence of Basel, which it is when using the prime-product form of the Riemann zeta function. They're using that as a jumping off point to look at a similar product.

Products of $p^s / (p^s-1)$ are given by the well-known Euler product (as in the answer below). Using the identity $(p^2-1)(p^2+1) = (p^4-1)$ allows you to get an expression for your product. You can use the same idea it to also get an expression for the product of $p^4/(p^4+1)$, $p^8/(p^8+1)$, $p^{16}/(p^{16}+1)$ and so on.

I found the answer to the second question myself:
$$
\prod_{n}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} = \sqrt{\Gamma(i)\Gamma(-i)} = \sqrt{\pi csch \pi} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e^\pi - e^-\pi}} \approx 0.5215640468649398
$$
Which also happens to be |i!|

Using the Euler product for $\zeta$ as well as its few known values at positive even integers we get $$\prod_{p}\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^{2}+1}}=\prod_{p}\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^{2}-1}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{p^{2}-1}{p^{2}+1}}
=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\prod_{p}\sqrt{\frac{p^{2}-1}{p^{2}+1}}$$$$=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\sqrt{\prod_{p}\frac{p^{2}-1}{p^{2}+1}}
=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\zeta\left(4\right)}{\zeta^{2}\left(2\right)}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\approx0.811...$$

Thanks for the answer! And my bad, I added the wrong number, 0.52156404... is what I got for the product over all natural numbers, not over the primes. In the latter case I indeed also got 0.8111.... I will edit the original post now accordingly

I think it's a little clearer to note that $\prod_p p/\sqrt{p^2+1} = \bigl( \prod_p (1+p^{-2}) \bigr)^{-1/2}$ combined with $\prod_p (1+p^{-s}) = \prod_p (1-p^{-2s})/(1-p^{-s}) = \zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$.

For me this is the most intuitive solution:
$$
\zeta(4) = \prod_{p}\frac{p^4}{p^4 - 1} = \prod_{p}\frac{p^2}{p^2 - 1}\prod_{p}\frac{p^2}{p^2 + 1} = \zeta(2) * \prod_{p}\frac{p^2}{p^2 + 1}
$$
And therefor:
$$
\prod_{p}\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2 + 1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\zeta(4)}{\zeta(2)}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{15}}
$$
